# Asset Pipeline in a sinatra app

Tags: ruby, module, sinatra, asset-pipeline

I have been trying to follow a guide to setting up the asset pipeline in a sinatra app, the aim to reduce my http requests when loading my web page.The guide is [Located Here](https://mutelight.org/asset-pipeline)

I think im stumbling on creating a module within a sinatra app, apologies if this is basic but havent done this before.

So i created a folder called modules and placed an assets.rb file within it. I have modified the script to suit my needs

```
class Assets < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    set :assets, (Sprockets::Environment.new { |env|
      env.append_path(settings.root + "/assets/js")
      env.append_path(settings.root + "/assets/css")

      # compress everything in production
      if ENV["RACK_ENV"] == "development || production"
        env.js_compressor  = YUI::JavaScriptCompressor.new
        env.css_compressor = YUI::CssCompressor.new
      end
    })
  end

  get "/assets/js/app.js" do
   content_type("application/javascript")
   settings.assets["app.js"]
  end

  get "/assets/css/app.css" do
   content_type("text/css")
   settings.assets["app.css"]
  end
end
```

my assets directory structure

```
assets
  css
    app.css
    other.css
  js
    app.js
    other.js
```

my config.ru

```
require './david'
use Assets
run Sinatra::Application
```

In each of my app.js and app.css i have put

```
 // require_tree
```

but in my js file it is greyed out and in the css it is still in white?

I have installed both gems required but still when loading the page there are multiple http requests rather than grouping all the css and js as one call

Can anyone see anything im missing, mainly the module setup im guessing?

Thanks

EDIT

My current layout file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <title>David's Carpets</title>

 <!--stylesheets-->
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" %>
 <!--[if IE 7]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
 <![endif]-->    
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "/assets/css/custom.min.css" %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "/assets/css/resp-980.min.css" %>


 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
 <%= styled_flash %>


 <%= yield %>
 <%= erb :footer %>


<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-1.7-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/valid_mail.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/twitter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve by this? Sometimes it's best not to take an approach from a different framework as it doesn't fit. Instead of focussing on the implementation you want, perhaps we could focus on the aim, and then you'd get better responses?

Comment: well im trying to implement use of the asset pipeline in a sinatra app.so that i can make fewer http requests to load my css and javascript

Comment: well for now I have put all my css in one stylesheet and all my js into a javascript file, but not the most elegant way

Comment: Sorry Rich, I wasn't able to look into this yesterday. I know it can seem an obvious question as to why you'd want to use Sprockets, but it does so much that it's possible you don't need or want some aspect. Do the assets get precompiled ok, and into one file? And is it possible for you to provide the layout or view where you call the assets? I'll post an answer as to how I handle assets below, though I don't use Sprockets, and what may be wrong with the code above.

Comment: thanks iain that would be appreciated, ill post layout file

Comment: I've answered, and added a bit now I've seen the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd be better to add the root path using a proc:

```
set :assets, Proc.new { Sprockets::Environment.new(root) {|env|
  env.append_path File.join( root, "/assets/js")
  env.append_path File.join(root, "/assets/css")
  # more…
}}
```

See if that improves things. You might want to use `Pry` or just `warn` to check that the value of `settings.assets["app.js"]` is what you expect it to be.

#### Workarounds

Like I said in the comments above, things don't always map well from one framework to another. Personally, I precompile my assets using [Guard/SASS](https://rubygems.org/gems/guard-sass) and [Guard/Coffeescript](https://rubygems.org/gems/guard-coffeescript) into the [public folder](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Static%20Files). There are also minification libraries that hook up with [Guard](https://rubygems.org/gems/guard) I then use [Sinatra Static Assets](https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-static) or [Sinatra Exstatic](https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-exstatic-assets)* to point to the files in views/layouts. I don't like to combine the javascript into one file (YMMV).

I also wanted the jQuery stuff that Rails added in via jquery-rails, so I wrote [rack-jquery](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-jquery), [rack-jquery_ui](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-jquery_ui), and [rack-jquery_ui-themes](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-jquery_ui-themes). They may be of interest to you.

Another way to get Sprockets working for you would be to use Rack. I found this blog post that shows you how:

http://metabates.com/2011/08/31/using-sprockets-without-rails/

- I also wrote Sinatra Exstatic, it's a fork of Sinatra Static Assets. It's a recent fork, if you use it any feedback will be welcome :)

---

Additional, now that the templates are posted in the question:

Sinatra won't do anything magic for you to point to the "super" css/js file, so if you have several CSS and javascript links then a client will still make several requests to the individual files. One way around this would be (in the case of the JS) to only have one statement, e.g:

```
<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="/assets/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and that's it. Another way to do this would be to keep all the statements you've got, but catch every statement using the route, e.g:

```
  # The local variable `name` isn't used below
  # but just in case you ever need it, it's there
  get "/assets/js/:name.js" do |name|
   content_type :javascript
   settings.assets["app.js"]
  end
```

Comment: thank iain.. what i have done is basically this <script src="/assets/js/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and the same for my css, minified everything into one file... is this ok as far as a best practice goes would you say, or am i only doing what the asset pipeline would do anyway? If you wouldn't mind I have another question regarding gzip http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813270/gzip-assets-in-sinatra-app

Comment: What you've done sounds fine. One big difference between Sinatra and Rails is that you have to do some of the work Rails' stuff would do for you, but then you also get the extra flexibility that you wouldn't with Rails. In a way, there's no best practice, just what works :) I'll take a look at the other question.