# gzip assets in Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, performance, sinatra, gzip, assets

I have been reading that zipping your assets using gzip will increase the performance of a site. There seems to be many ways to do this in a Sinatra application, so i was looking to confirm the most effective and easiest way to understand.

I have come across

```
use Rack::Deflater
```

Which should be placed in my config.ru file before running the app, so in my case

```
require './david'
use Rack::Deflater
run Sinatra::Application
```

is that it? is it this simple, Just to add I know this will zip all my static assets, including my images, but these are served from a CDN so would that make a difference?

Ant help appreciated with this one

Thanks

Comment: If your assets not served from your sinatra app they won't get gzip

Comment: yeah i thought so, its the css and js i want to gzip, im not worried about the images

Comment: and don't forget don't use gzip for binary data and pic's https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#GzipCompression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is that easy (isn't that nice:) but if you want to check, then look at the `Content-Encoding` response header and it should say `gzip`. In a webkit browser it's in the developer tools under "Network", then select the resource, like `app.min.css` and the "Headers" tab.

A way to test for this is given in the following blog post:

http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/02/24/10x-rack-and-rails-output-compression-with-rack-deflater/

I modified the specs into [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples), so I can add them in where I really want to check:

```
shared_examples "Compressed pages" do
  subject { last_response.headers }
  its(["Content-Encoding"]) { should be_nil }
  context "After compression" do
    before do
      get page
      @etag = last_response.headers["Etag"]
      @content_length = last_response.headers["Content-Length"]
      get page, {}, { "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => "gzip" }
    end
    its(["Etag"]) { should == @etag }
    its(["Content-Length"]) { should_not == @content_length }
    its(["Content-Encoding"]) { should == "gzip"}
  end
end
```

My main spec uses it like this:

```
  describe "Public pages" do

    describe "Home page", :type => :request do
      let(:page) { "/" }
      it_behaves_like "Compressed pages"
```

The `it_behaves_like "Compressed pages"` will run that shared example and check it has the right header etc.

Comment: thanks for the clarification and also thanks for the extra info with regards to tests :) using something other than rails makes you realise how much it does for you, but its also good to do these things to understand more

Comment: @Richlewis it's true, Rails does a lot, but Sinatra is so lightweight and flexible that once you're into it, you won't miss Rails much :)

Comment: any good resources for using models and modules within Sinatra? I really need to get up to speed with that

Comment: @Richlewis I use Sequel but I know a lot of people like to use Datamapper - I think most people take the opportunity to avoid ActiveRecord! :) Some of the best stuff on using ORM's with Sinatra is right here on StackOverflow. The modules stuff is covered quite well in the documentation, [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps), [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions-wild.html) and [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html).